# Crystal Report-FORMULA

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I am trying to create two FORMULA fields in Crystal Reports with the same Column in the Database using the following Syntax:

```
FORMULA1- COLL_DATE
if Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Cleared'
then Coll_Rej_Dt
else null

FORMULA2- REJ_DATE
if Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Rejected'
then Coll_Rej_Dt
else null
```

But it is giving me error saying "a Date and Time Field is expected here"

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to return `Coll_Rej_Dt` when the condition is correct, otherwise return `null`.

you can use Switch by replace if condition. Because in if condition, you need to return same data type in true part and false part.

So, try this...

```
Switch (Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Cleared', Coll_Rej_Dt)

Switch (Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Rejected', Coll_Rej_Dt)
```

this will return value when the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

you can't give one value as date time and other as null in a if condition.. change like this:

FORMULA1- COLL_DATE

```
if Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Cleared' 
then ToText(Coll_Rej_Dt) 
else ""
```

FORMULA2- REJ_DATE

```
if Collection_Rejection_Desc = 'Rejected'
then ToText(Coll_Rej_Dt )
else ""
```